# Calling an async method inside another async method does not work in office js. Using the command script used from the Ribbon in a web browser

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

Do you know why this function called from my script commands.ts which is a script used by the commands in the ribbon wouldn't work?

I am creating an Add-in for Outlook and I am calling the method "join" which is triggered when the button from the ribbon is clicked. The issue I am having is that when I am in the browser the method "replaceAsync" never gets called so the notification is never added to the screen. If I run the application in Outlook desktop the notification shows absolutely fine (image 1). This is the method I am using, could you advise if what I am doing is correct and do you know what could be reason that is causing this issue in the browser?

Many Thanks

[Image displaying notification in Outlook Desktop app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLo5N.png)

```
function join(event: Office.AddinCommands.Event) {   
  Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync(Office.CoercionType.Html, result => {

    if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
       console.log('command failed')
   Office.context.mailbox.item.notificationMessages.replaceAsync("video", {
          type: Office.MailboxEnums.ItemNotificationMessageType.InformationalMessage,
          message: `No Matching Link Found`,
          icon: "Icon.80x80",
          persistent: false
       });
    } else {
      console.log('command success')
    }
  });
  event.completed();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [replaceAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.notificationmessages?view=outlook-js-preview#replaceAsync_key__JSONmessage__callback_) method replaces a notification message that has a given key with another message. When the method completes, the callback function passed in the callback parameter is called with a single parameter of type `Office.AsyncResult`. But in your sample code the optional parameter (callback) is omitted. So, you will never know when it finishes.

```
// Link to full sample: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OfficeDev/office-js-snippets/prod/samples/outlook/35-notifications/add-getall-remove.yaml
var id = $("#notificationId").val();
Office.context.mailbox.item.notificationMessages.replaceAsync(
  id,
  {
    type: "informationalMessage",
    message: "Notification message with id = " + id + " has been replaced with an informational message.",
    icon: "icon2",
    persistent: false
  },
  handleResult);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your response Eugene. Yes you are right I didn't add to my method the "handleResult" as callback option. After your suggestion I added it and I couldn't see any result back. My handleResult option was as the one bellow:

```
function handleResult() {
    console.log('replaced')
}
```

But then I found what the issue was. I was calling event.completed() outside of the method `Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync` so I never told to the host app that the processing finished. My working method looks like this now:

```
function join(event: Office.AddinCommands.Event) {   
  Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync(Office.CoercionType.Html, result => {

    if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
       console.log('command failed')
       Office.context.mailbox.item.notificationMessages.replaceAsync("video", {
          type: Office.MailboxEnums.ItemNotificationMessageType.InformationalMessage,
          message: `No Matching Link Found`,
          icon: "Icon.80x80",
          persistent: false
      });
    } else {
      console.log('command success')
       Office.context.mailbox.item.notificationMessages.replaceAsync("video", {
          type: Office.MailboxEnums.ItemNotificationMessageType.InformationalMessage,
          message: `Matching Link Found`,
          icon: "Icon.80x80",
          persistent: false
      });
    }
    **event.completed();**
  });
}
```

I hope this will be helpful for someone who faces the same issue.
Thanks!